# Backend parsing code which is called in some period of time

Tags: python, django

Project is based on creating own objects by parsing information from some website. So, own objects have to be up-to-date, but it would be weird and inefficient , if function(which parses updated information and saves it using Django ORM) is called for every user loading the page.

So I figured it might be some independent code, called with some frequency(like once a day) .

Is the concept right? And how to run a python/django function once in period of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are on Linux [`django-cron`](http://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) is a simple solution for running a task periodically.

Other solutions include [writing a management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands) and calling it from a cronjob or [using a task queue](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/) (though the latter option is probably a bit too complex for your actual use case).